# How to ensure all new subdirectories (and sub-subdirectories, etc.) have g+s?

Tags: permissions, group

If the group of `/some/dir` is `foo`, and I run

```
chmod g+s /some/dir
```

...then any child of `/some/dir` will also have group `foo`.

Crucially, however, a new subdirectory `/some/dir/subdir` will *not* have `g+s` (although, as just stated, it its group will be `foo`).

How can I ensure that all descendant subdirectories of `/some/dir` not only inherit the group `foo`, but also inherit the `g+s` permission?

FWIW, my umask is `002`, the filesystem is nfs, and the options according to `mount` are `(rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=20961,wsize=413177,namlen=255,hard‌​,proto=tcp,timeo=450‌​,retrans=2,sec=sys,m‌​ountaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx‌​.xxx,mountvers=3,mou‌​ntport=333,mountprot‌​o=udp,local_lock=non‌​e,addr=xxx.xxx.xxx.x‌​xx)`.

**UPDATE:**  I now understand the source of my confusion: *sometimes* changing a directory's group (with `chgrp`) has the effect of disabling a previously enabled setgid bit.  E.g.

```
% rm -rf /some/dir
% mkdir -p /some/dir
% chmod g+s /some/dir
% ls -ld /some/dir
drwxrwsr-x 2 jones jones 0 Nov  7 07:13 /some/dir
% chgrp foo /some/dir
% ls -ld /some/dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 jones jones 0 Nov  7 07:13 /some/dir
```

(Note that the setgid bit ends up unset.)

As I said, this happens only *sometimes*.  For example, if I repeat the same sequence above, but I run the `chgrp` command under `sudo`, then the `setgid` bit remains set at the end.

This effect of `chgrp` on the permissions is what threw me off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once `/some/dir` has the setgid bit, new subdirectories *do* inherit it, so all newly-created descendents have the appropriate group and setgid bit.

Using `chgrp` can drop the setgid bit. [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chgrp.html)

> Unless chgrp is invoked by a process with appropriate privileges, the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits of a regular file shall be cleared upon successful completion; the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits of other file types may be cleared.